# Arquillian, tomee-embedded and JAX-RS

Tags: jboss-arquillian, apache-tomee, jersey-2.0

I am using Arquillian with a tomee-embedded container in order to test my JAX-RS web service. In my test case, I am running a jersey test client accessing the provided resource. However, the test always results in a 404 NOT FOUND status when accessing the resource.

When deploying the same project on my tomee-jaxrs instance, the resource is provided properly.

These are the maven dependencies that I've included in my test project:

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.glassfish.jersey.core</groupId>
    <artifactId>jersey-server</artifactId>
    <version>${jersey.version}</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-tomee-embedded</artifactId>
    <version>${tomee.version}</version>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.junit</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-junit-container</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.shrinkwrap.resolver</groupId>
    <artifactId>shrinkwrap-resolver-depchain</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
```

My test case looks as follows:

```java
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class DemoTest {
    @Deployment
    public static WebArchive createDeployment() throws Exception {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(WebArchive.class).addPackage(Controller.class.getPackage()).setWebXML("ch/codenation/test/regression/resources/container/WEB-INF/web.xml");
    }

    @ArquillianResource
    private URL url;

    @Test
    public void testGetData() throws Exception {
        final IApplicationLayer applicationLayer = new JaxRsApplicationLayer(url.toURI());
        final Callable<String> dataProvider = new DataProvider(applicationLayer);
        Assert.assertEquals("asdf", dateProvider.call());
    }
}
```

As well as my web.xml:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd" version="3.0">
    <display-name>codenation-service</display-name>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>javax.ws.rs.core.Application</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

The JAX-RS resource is indeed unavailable, for when I put a breakpoint in the test method and try to access the resource in the browser, I receive a 404 message. Doing the same thing when deplyoing the archive to a tomee-jaxrs server works fine, however. Are there any additional maven dependencies or arquillian configuration settings I need to add here in order to make this work?

Thanks for any feedback and best regards
Pascal

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There seems to be no way to switch the tomee-embedded adapter to a plus configuration. I therefore switched over to the tomee-remote adapter.

Answer (score 2):

Just include this in your pom.xml

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.openejb</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomee-jaxrs</artifactId>
        <version>${tomee.version}</version>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
```

and you can work with the embedded TomEE.